# how to get int with fstream get() in c++

Tags: c++, file

I am a newer to C++,
Now what I am going to do is creating a file, and write int values into it
Then I want to get those int values with get function!(Here the excepted type of return is int )
Actually this is an index file, so what I am going to put into it are all int values! 
But I found that both fstream.put and fstream.get could only operate char values.
So is there anyone would like to help me, how to do my job.
And here is my code

```
vector<int> tra1;
vector<int> tra2;
int last_capa = 0;
    for(int i=1;i<97;i++){
        output.put(tra1[i-1] * 5 + tra2[i-1] + last_capa);
        last_capa += (tra1[i-1] - 1) * 5 + tra2[i - 1];
    }
```

Below is the code to read int
Here I try to get an int number to operate

```
vector<int> tra4
output.seekg(100);
unsigned int n = output.get() + tra4[2];
```

Thanks for your help

Haoran

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672991/proper-casting-for-fstream-read-and-write-member-functions

You have to cast what you're reading from `char*` to the type you want to read.

Comment: Your file does not contain "int values". It contains text that looks like numbers to a human (when rendered per ASCII).

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively instead of get, you can use the fstream's operator >> to read the value from the file into an int.

```
fstream fs("input.txt", std::fstream::in); //input file
int k;
while(fs >> k)
{
   //do something with k
}
fs.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the fstream operator >> is to use read/write. To write an int value:

```
std::ofstream f_out("my_file.txt", std::ofstream::binary);
int n;
f_out.write((char *) & ( n ), sizeof(n));
```

An to read:

```
std::ifstream("my_file.txt", std::ifstream::binary);
int n;
f_in.read((char *)&n, sizeof(n));
```

To read the 100th int:

```
std::ifstream("my_file.txt", std::ifstream::binary);
f_in.seekg(100*sizeof(int), std::ios::beg);
int n;
f_in.read((char *)&n, sizeof(n));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the oldish C method sprintf to put some int in a string, and then put the string in your file like so :

```
sprintf(theNameOfYourString,"%d",n);
```

EDIT : Of course then you have to put the string theNameOfYourString in your file, sprintf only allows you to place things in a String.

Comment: Usually in `C++` one would overload `operator<<` to achieve the same result.

Comment: Thanks for your help Roncoli. But if I do it in your method how can I get the int value back?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I suppose the get() function returns a String. You can do operations on this String, such as atoi(), that converts a String to an int.

EDIT : Here is a link : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/